# XCTestCase superclass methods not visible to subclass

Tags: xcode, inheritance, xctest

I created the following XCTestCase superclass:

```
//  FileNameTest.h

#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface FileNameTest : XCTestCase

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END

//  FileNameTest.m

#import "FileNameTest.h"

@implementation FileNameTest
- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];
}

- (void)tearDown {
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)helloMessage{
  NSLog(@"Hello");
}

@end
```

And a subclass that invokes the superclass method:

```
//  FilenamePatternTest1.m

#import "FileNameTest.h"

@interface FilenamePatternTest1 : FileNameTest

@end

@implementation FilenamePatternTest1

- (void)testExample {
  [self helloMessage];
}

@end
```

But the subclass won't compile. Error message reads:

> No visible @interface for 'FilenamePatternTest1' declares the selector 'helloMessage'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective-C can't see declarations made in a `.m` file. You will need to declare the methods you want to call in your superclass' `.h` file.